# How to make navigation to the desired PivotItem using Prism? UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, prism, uwp

I have a menu, and when I click on a menu item I want to navigate to a page to a particular PivotItem.
I think there must be something like this

```
_navigationService.Navigate(path**item=2**, ObjectContainer);
```

Comment: Great! Have fun implementing it! If you get stuck, feel free to ask a question on here complete with what you have tried/researched and why that didn't solve your problem. Read [ask] for more guidelines

Comment: If you do not know the answer/don't want to help, please don't write anything. Don't flood, please.
I have been looking for a solution and found it only to the codebehind. If I knew how to do it using mvvm, I would not write here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote a demo to solve your problem. I see that you may use a navigationService in your project, I didn't use it, and i didn't use any menu here, just a very simple demo, OK?

Yes you are right to use the navigation with argument passing, so it become the problem how you receive this argument in your `Pivot` page and handle this argument.

To do this, you need to override the `OnNavigatedTo()` method in your `Pivot` Page:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="PivotItem 1" Click="Button_Click1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30"/>
    <Button Content="PivotItem 2" Click="Button_Click2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30"/>
    <Button Content="PivotItem 3" Click="Button_Click3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="30"/>
</StackPanel>
```

PivotPage.xaml:

```
<Pivot Title="Test" FontSize="60" x:Name="pivotcontrol">
    <PivotItem Header="Item1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="PivotItem1" FontSize="30" Margin="60"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Item2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="PivotItem2" FontSize="30" Margin="60"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Item3">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="PivotItem3" FontSize="30" Margin="60"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
<Button Content="Back to MainPage" Margin="60" Click="item_back"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PivotPage), "Item1");
        }

        private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PivotPage), "Item2");
        }

        private void Button_Click3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PivotPage), "Item3");
        }
```

PivotPage.xaml.cs:

```
string selectitem = null;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        string getdata = e.Parameter.ToString();
        selectitem = getdata;
    }

    if (selectitem.Equals("Item1"))
    {
        pivotcontrol.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    else if (selectitem.Equals("Item2"))
    {
        pivotcontrol.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        pivotcontrol.SelectedIndex = 2;
    }
}

public PivotPage()
{  
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

private void item_back(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```